# How do I add a video onto my form in a Delphi TMS WEB Core project?

Tags: delphi, html5-video, tms, tms-web-core

When I search for "image" in the Component Palette, I find many image-related components and I can use the `TWebImageControl` component to add a images onto my form:

[image: Delphi IDE]

But when I search for "video" in the Component Palette, then I get nothing:

[image: Delphi Component Palette]

Are there no video-related components?

How can I add a video to my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component for adding a video to a form is the [`TWebMultimediaPlayer`](https://download.tmssoftware.com/doc/tmswebcore/components/twebmultimediaplayer/) component.

You can then use the following properties to configure the video:

- `URL`: Link to the video file
- `AutoPlay`: Boolean to set if the content will start playing as soon as it is ready
- `Loop`: Boolean to set if the content is played in a continuous loop
- `Controls`: Boolean to set if the playback controls are displayed

The `TWebMultimediaPlayer` component will be compiled into a `<video>` HTML tag.